# How and when to finish a Cedar or redwood fence?

Tags: wood, fence, wood-finish

My neighbor and I are putting up a fence between our properties. We will use either Cedar or Redwood.  The fence will have vertical boards on both sides bc we want both of the fence surfaces to look nice from our respective properties.

My question is should we finish/treat the fence AFTER it is installed or treat the wood before it is installed?

Also after it ages how do I treat the wood? Note: There will be faces that are 'hidden'... the back sides of the faces that we see from our properties.

Comment: Building an "alternating board fence" (Google that) saves significantly on materials, allows some air thru and releaves wind pressure, and allows you to reach all surfaces with any treatments.

Comment: I've seen those designs. I'll revisit that design with the neighbor. But I think we are 95% decided in doing a tongue and groove fence on both sides.

Comment: A double-faced fence makes a cavity which can harbor unwanted critters. Our next door neighbor put up an alternating board fence and it provides almost as much privacy as a single layer privacy fence.

Comment: I have found if any sun hits cedar , it will need to be treated every 3 years. I let mine go natural grey.

Comment: @blacksmith37 does treating it prevent it from going grey?

Comment: We're in Los Angeles so here won't be water damage only sun damage...

Comment: The repeated preservative treatments prevent it from turning grey.

Comment: I have never seen a redwood or cedar fence that did not turn gray over the years unless painted or stained to a color. Most will water seal if natural finish is wanted but this will take annually applying sealers and over the years the will still turn in my experiances.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you treat before install and get all sides, later down you will have to just treat the visible portion, unless you plan to pull the fence down and retreat then put back up....in my opinion, too much work.